# How to solve this Firebase auth/rejected-credential

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

This is my code that im doing auth. I've used @react-native-firebase/auth for this. I've downloaded google-services.json file and placed in the android folder.

Now if I run the code and after entering the Phone Number It is throwing error that:

[Error: [auth/rejected-credential] The request contains malformed or mismatching credentials [ App ID does not match requested project. ]]

How to solve this?

```
handleSendCode = () => {
    // Request to send OTP
    if (this.validatePhoneNumber()) {
      auth()
        .signInWithPhoneNumber(this.state.phone)
        .then(confirmResult => {
          this.setState({ confirmResult })
        })
        .catch(error => {
          alert(error.message)
          console.log(error)
        })
    } else {
      alert('Invalid Phone Number')
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Everyone I got the answer fro my question.

Firstly I've followed the [fire base](https://rnfirebase.io/auth/phone-auth/) rules and I've created one project and later due to this error i have deleted that project in fiebase and created new project . But here I didn't noticed that the SHA key which is generated is already assigned to a project and for this reason i was not getting.

Now Created a new project and followed the rules and all now i got the error solved.

Answer (score 0):

most likely this is about the issue, that when you create firebase project you must define ID of your project, like a package name. After firebase generates for you the json  file that you put to your project.

So if id of project is not the same as in generated json file, there will be issue.

Comment: While Creating the project It will ask only for Package name And SHA key Right?

Answer (score 0):

There are three reasons why you might be getting `auth/rejected-credential` error:

1. The `google-services.json` file you are using has invalid projectId. This is highly unlikely since you downloaded it from Firebase directly.
2. Your Firebase Project Settings is missing Android SHA certificate fingerprint that matches your certificate in Android Keystore.
   [Here you can find instructions how to find SHA cert fingerprint.](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth)
   Firebase Projects can have many SHA fingerprints assigned, however **only one project can be assigned to a SHA fingerprint**.
3. Your Auto-generated [Android API key in Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) has SHA fingerprint restriction assigned that doesn't match the Android certificate you are using when building your application.

Comment: But I've added SHA key As in the official Doc and After That downloaded the google-services.json file. Ive followed all the steps that is mentioned. It is working Fine For Firestore.

Comment: Did you add your debug keystore SHA as well?